# Apex Oracle calendar When Select list value is null show all and when Select value is not null show filtered

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

What I want to achieve is :

- when the select value is null -> all the appointments show up
- when the select value is set -> only the appointments for that specific doctor.

*Query :*

```
SELECT a.ward_id,
       a.doc_id,
       a.id_patient,
       a.dt_Sched,
       a.dt_Sched_end,
       a.sched_time,
       to_char(a.sched_duration,'0.0') sched_duration,
       a.sched_id,
       a.hosp_ward,
       c.surname||' '||c.name || ' - time :' ||a.sched_time  Display,
       d.description 
  FROM t_schedule a,
       T_doctors  b,
       t_patient  c,
       t_Ward     d
 WHERE a.doc_id = b.doc_id 
   and c.id_patient = a.id_patient 
  /* and b.doc_id = :PselectList*/ > Select list for which doctor 
   and d.ward_id= a.ward_id
```

**without : 'and b.doc_id = :PselectList'**

- shows me all the appointments in the calendar

**with : 'and b.doc_id = :PselectList'**

- if select value is set to null --> no appointments in the calendar
- if select value is set not null doctor --> shows filtered appointments in the calendar by selected value

Answer (score 1):

Solved with ***nvl*** :

```
WHERE a.doc_id = b.doc_id 
   and c.id_patient = a.id_patient 
   and b.doc_id = nvl(:PselectList, b.doc_id)
   and d.ward_id= a.ward_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then it should be

```
from t_schedule a join t_doctors b on a.doc_id = b.doc_id
                  join t_patient c on c.id_patient = a.id_patient
                  join t_ward d on d.ward_id = a.ward_id
where (b.doc_id = :P3008_SELECTLIST or :P3008_SELECTLIST is null)
```

---

(BTW, do you really use MS SQL Server as a database? Is it not Oracle? If so, fix tags.)